# how is the best way to create a struct in a loop?

Tags: matlab, indexing, struct

I want to create a struct in a loop. this is the initial command lines:

```
for i = 1:n
     if condition
         myStruct(i).a = i:
         myStruct(i).b = 1:
     else
         myStruct(i) = myFunction(i):
     end
 end
```

myFunction is as follow: (real one has more fields)

```
function myStruct = myFunction(i)
myStruct.a = i;
myStruct.b = 0;
end
```

when the condition is true for the very first loop (i=1) it works fine, otherwise there is an error with the first assignment as follow:

```
subscripted assignment between dissimilar structures.
```

In order to Cope it I did as following but I'm looking for a better more efficient solution.

```
for i = 1:n
     if condition
         myStruct(i).a = i:
         myStruct(i).b = 1:
     else
         if i == 1
             myStruct = myFunction(i);
         else
             myStruct(i) = myFunction(i):
         end
     end
 end
```

but I prefer some shorter solution. I appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: You seem to need  just `for k=1:n,  myStruct(k) = myFunction(k);  end`

Comment: @SardarUsama that how I was getting error and tried to fixed it with the if block.

Comment: Does it work if you do `temp = myFunction(i);` then `myStruct(i)=temp` ?

Comment: @hyiltiz No. I tried that, same error. when myStruct is still empty can not be indexed anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have already commented here: Preallocate, and forget about the `i==1` case.

```
myStruct(n) = myFunction(n); % or any other way of creating an instance of your structure, not important. 
for i = 1:n
     if condition
         myStruct(i).a = i:
         myStruct(i).b = 1:
     else
         myStruct(i) = myFunction(i):
     end
 end
```

Answer (score 3):

Using arrayfun is more efficient for this.  If myFunction always returns a struct with the same members, try:

```
myStruct = arrayfun(@myFunction, 1:n);
```

Edit for clarification:

When you add on every iteration you are changing the dimension of the array every iteration.  This is not efficient.  Arrayfun allows Matlab to preallocate the struct array and manage value assignment for you.

Edit to address edited OP

Updated function:

```
function myStruct = myFunction(i, condition)
myStruct.a = i;
if condition
    myStruct.b = 1;
else
    myStruct.b = 0;
end
end
```

Updated call:

```
s = arrayfun(@(x) myFunction(x, condition), 1:n);
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is more efficient (array fun is just a for loop), but definetly more elegant.

Comment: Try it with very large values of n.

Comment: Right, but that does not make this faster, OP could have preallocated his array, they just didn't. Its not faster because its `arrayfun`, its faster because it preallocates, which is irrelevant from the loop vs arrayfun speed.

Comment: Fair enough.  The code in the OP does not preallocate.  The OP was looking for a shorter solution, arrayfun provides that.  I just ran a quick test between the 2 methods with 10k iterations.  Arrayfun took 0.2083 seconds, the OP method took 1.4782.

Comment: @Jeremy thanks, but in my case it doesn't work, because there is another if before the for loop, that for some "i"s another block is executed. I removed that for simplicity. I will edit my question.

Comment: do `a(n) = myfun(n);` to preallocate ;). Just commenting, I upvoted this answer.

Comment: @Jeremy thanks again for the useful explanation but that is not the solution to my question. I edited my question with more detail so you or others may find it.

Comment: @prs Why not include the condition in the input parameters of myFunction and let it handle the assignment?

Comment: @Jeremy the condition is not the problem. when myStruct is still empty I cannot assign to it with indexing. So pre-allocating seems to be the solution.